# OData V4 to access secured URI

Tags: wpf, odata

I need to develolp a WPF application that use the OData service of a Project Online Server. When I try to reference the OData service with ODataLib V4, it doesn't work because the OData service is secure.

Anyone know a workaround for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

1. Extract the metadata of Project Online in xml file (https://[your pwa site]/_api/ProjectData/$metadata)
2. Change the extension of the xml file to .edmx
3. Execute DataSvcUtil in your Framework directory (DataSvcUtil /in:edmxfile.edmx /out:csfile.cs /language:CSharp)
4. Add the csfile.cs in your .Net Project
5. Add the following references in your project :

   ```
   - Microsoft.SharePoint.Client
   - Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.DocumentManagement
   - Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing
   - Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime
   - Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.Windows
   - Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy
   - Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles
   - Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WorkflowServices
   - Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.Activities
   - Microsoft SharePoint Solutions Framework
   ```

Here, an example of the code :

```
    private const string PSDATA = "https://[your pwa site]";

    ProjectOData.ReportingData context =
            new ProjectOData.ReportingData(new Uri(PSDATA + "/_api/ProjectData/", UriKind.Absolute)) { IgnoreMissingProperties = true };

    var username = <username>;
    var password = <password>;

    var secureString = new System.Security.SecureString();
    foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray())
    {
        secureString.AppendChar(c);
    }

    context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, secureString);

    SharePointOnlineCredentials credentials = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, secureString);

    var authenticationCookie = credentials.GetAuthenticationCookie(new Uri(PSDATA));

    context.SendingRequest += delegate (object sender, SendingRequestEventArgs e)
    {
        e.RequestHeaders.Clear();
        e.RequestHeaders.Add("Cookie", authenticationCookie);
    };

    var projectQuery1 = from p in context.Projects
                        select p;
```